# How to use Laravel authentication for wordpress blog inside laravel web application

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-5, wordpress-theming

I've installed Wordpress inside my Laravel app to manage blog content and other stuff.
Now I need user Laravel authentication for accessing wordpress. Is it possible to do that ? If yes, how?

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41813124/470749

Comment: I posted a full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198453/470749

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need Laravel authentication for accessing wordpress blog. Unauthenticated users should not be able to access it.

If this is the case. Solution is listed below.

**Your Blog url:** site_url/blog { it can be wordpress folder name inside laravel }

**Edit** ( routes/web.php )

```
Route::get('/blog', 'AdminPagesController@blog');
```

**AdminPagesController**

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Request;
 use Carbon\Carbon;

 class AdminPagesController extends Controller {

  /**
  * Create a new controller instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct() {
    //It will check if logged in, if not redirect to login page
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function blog(){
    // Simple return, wordpress will handle rest if authenticated person access the url
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to make this work is reading the `index.php` from WordPress inside your Laravel controller with

```
ob_start();
require '/path/to/wp/index.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
return response($html);
```

However if you want to use Laravel with a CMS, there are better (native) options like [October CMS](https://octobercms.com/).

Comment: Found an answer to my question using this **https://github.com/lehoangduc/wl-bootstrap**. It's a WordPress plugin that helps you use functions, methods, libraries of Laravel in any WordPress projects.