# Wordpress login from Laravel 5.5

Tags: wordpress, laravel, authentication

I installed the Laravel appliction and integrate the wordpress in public directory.

My website url like this
Laravel http://dev.local
Wordpress http://dev.local/blog

I use the [corecel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel) pacakge for get the information from the wordpress to laravel, i am facing one issue, how i can auto login to wordpress dashbaord so when user login inside the laravel. I know the wp-load.php file need to include and then use the following code.

```
$userid = $user->ID;
wp_set_auth_cookie($userid);
do_action('wp_login',$userid);
```

I used the approach with another code-igniter application its working. Any one guide me how to achieve the same thing in Laravel.

Possible solution
1. Login with the curl when Laravel authentication.

```
$username="admin";
  $password="admin";
  $url="http://dev.local/golf/";
  $cookie="cookie.txt";

  $postdata = "log=". $username ."&pwd=". $password ."&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=". $url ."wp-admin/&testcookie=1";
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "wp-login.php");
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "wp-admin/");
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;
```

Note: The curl request give this. Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Solution 2: Load the wp-laod.php and set the cookie.

```
Route::get('/wordpress', function(){
require('..\wordpress\wp-load.php');
return loginUser(Auth::user()->username);
});
```

Note: Its give the following error. FatalErrorException in l10n.php line 203:Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in

Please anyone guide me on this how to achieve auto login Wordpress, when user login in laravel.

Comment: Could you past the full error report? It seems that a file is included multiple time, or 2 functions have the same `__` signature.

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41813124/470749