# Laravel User to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have a 'Laravel' Based Website. I have Lots of Users. How can I connect those users to 'wordpress', so the 'Laravel' User can login to 'wordpress' with the same access. I have been searching a lot, but no one gave a good answer.

Comment: Have you looked at Socialite's Wordpress provider? https://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/wordpress/

Comment: Its for wordpress.com i think i get for my site which download from wordpress.org

Comment: Just create the user in the wordpress database directly... That is quite simple in fact if you have access to it...

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35643938/470749

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress SSO plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/sso/)

Try different wordpress SSO plugins / Methods in which while user access wordpress login with laravel user credentails that time 
during word press it check, if same user available in word press database or not?

1) If user not exist in word press database create user and logged into word press

2) If user already exist in word press database logged into word press.

Comment: Thank u is there any tutorial for that i can follow up

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/sso-authentication-integration-with-external-directory-service

Comment: There are multiple plugins free / purchasable for SSO purpose in wordpress.