# Facebook Login With WP JWT Auth

Tags: wordpress, jwt, facebook-login, wordpress-rest-api

We are using WP [JWT Auth plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) to login user to WordPress from wp rest API. WP JWT Auth plugin requires a password to get the token, now when we are integrating facebook login, I am not sure how to get the user logged in since we won't be having passwords from facebook.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for assuming that you were using ionic in my answer below, if you are not using ionic then you handle the login token normally, using javascript or whatever

Comment: You might benefit from my very thorough answer here about how to automatically log in to a WordPress site via JWT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198453/470749

Answer (score 6):

Yesterday I opened a bounty for your question and today I'm answering it!

You will need two WordPress plugins: [stionic users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stionic-users/) and [nextend social login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/) (you need to configure it on order for stionic to work. Watch the video on that page in order to know how to configure it)

When done you could send a post request to `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/m_facebook/login`in postman and you will notice that you will get the same token that you get when logging in `https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token`

After that, you can configure [facebook ionic plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/) and you are done.

[JSON API User plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/) is an alternative but I haven't tried it

Useful tutorials

[Facebook ionic login](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw46diR8rAs) - [Wordpress ionic login](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiXs7hrmmmg)

Comment: I haven't tried this solution yet, if anyone does please comment here.

Comment: @ZainSohail  I tried it for a client, it worked and published the app for him.

Comment: I've try this way but I get json error message like this:
`{
    "code": "users_can_not_register",
    "message": "Registration disabled",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}`
I have enabled membership to WordPress default setting.