# How to check the status of x-session?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using angular 6, consuming a rest api, the backend is laravel php. There's no token, if you are logged in, you get an x-session, you can see it in postman headers

```
X-Session →1948c514b7e5669c284e85d6f612f9bd491
X-Session-Expiry →2038-08-02T09:19:03+00:00
```

How to check the value of the `x-session` and `X-Session-Expiry` from angular? There's nothing related to session in the api endpoind. I need to know if the session is still open and when the session expires, I need to log the user out.

Can those x-session values be accessed from angular when you login? are they stored in the header?

Service

```
  login(username, password) {
    const data = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    localStorage.setItem('headers', JSON.stringify(headers));
    return this.http.post(this.login_url, data, { headers: headers });
  }
```

And I have tried to supply the same session to the users service

```
  getUsers() {
    const headers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('headers'));
    return this.http.get(this.users_url, { headers: headers });
  }
```

But it doesn't work, I don't get any user, is there a solution for that?

Comment: I solved the problem but since there's an open bounty, if you come up with a better solution, I'll accept your answer and give you the bounty, I mean it's an open bounty that has to be awarded to someone or it expires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twice in 1 week, I open a bounty to a question then I answer it, what can I do? I can't delete it.

So it turns out I need to change my  login function

```
  login(username, password) {
    const data = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(this.login_url, data, { headers: headers, observe: 'response' });
  }
```

And that's how you get the x-session

```
  onLogin() {
    this.auth.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => {
      this.auth.setLoggedIn(true);
      localStorage.setItem('login', JSON.stringify(this.auth.isLoggedIn));
      if (localStorage.getItem('data') === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
      }
      const session = data.headers.get('x-session');
      const expiry = data.headers.get('x-session-expiry');
      localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session));
      localStorage.setItem('session-expiry', JSON.stringify(expiry));


      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

And this is how you use it, for example `getUsers` from above

```
  getUsers() {
    const session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
    if (session != null) {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers = headers.set('x-session', session);
      return this.http.get(this.users_url, { headers: headers });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot revoke a bounty. If you choose to write out a bounty on a question, that reputation is gone no matter what.

Comment: @IngoBürk yeah i did it twice in a week, today i opened a  bounty for this question then answered it now. Last week I opened a bounty for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274669/facebook-login-with-wp-jwt-auth/51584193#51584193 and answered it the next day. It's okay as long as we get the answer and extend our knowledge it's perfectly okay, but I don't know why I rush to open a bounty rather than spending more time figuring out. I don't like this about me